# vi explore with subdirectories and files

Tags: vim

When using :ex or :sex with vim, how can all of the files and subdirectories in the tree be shown? Currently when using the explore function, only the current directorie's contents are shown.

For example, I'd like to have:

```
/
   /controllers
      posts.php
   /models
      posts_model.php
   /public_html
      js/
         lightbox.js
   /views
      homepage.php
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, netrw does have a tree listing mode. You can press `i` to toggle between its different modes.

Or you can set this to permanently default to tree listing:

```
let g:netrw_liststyle=3
```

Note that this can be VERY SLOW in large directories.

Answer (score 1):

The *netrw* plugin that ships with Vim only shows the contents of the current directory itself by default. If you want something like a file explorer (with expandable folders etc.), you need to reconfigure (cp. Dan Fitch's answer), or switch to a specialized, more powerful plugin. [NERDtree](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658) is a popular one.

Comment: No, `netrw` does have expandable folders.

Comment: @romainl: Thanks, didn't know about that option. Nonetheless, I think NERDtree is more powerful in this respect (I recently started using it), so I'm keeping the answer.